# How to set empty date field with arcpy.CalculateField_Management?

Tags: arcpy

I want to simply set my date field to empty i.e "". No problem directly in ArcGIS , but with arcpy I can´t seem to get the syntax right. When I try with a date this is no problem e.g '22.06.2015' But with '' it doesn´t work.

```
arcpy.CalculateField_management(fc, item, '',"PYTHON")
```

Comment: Have you tried a null or `NoneType` in python?  I don't know if it will assign a null date or not?

Comment: I´ve tried NULL - this doesn´t work.

Answer (score 7):

Use the python `None` statement:

```
arcpy.CalculateField_management(fc, item, 'None',"PYTHON")
```

This is the literal for the NoneType that Branco mentioned. It appears that it will work with all field types (I did test with a DATE and it worked for me), although I've not tried it with everything.

Comment: I guess this works for non-string fields only? If you did this on a String field it would insert the word None rather than set it to Nothing.

Comment: @Hornbydd Be sure to not double quote `None` (it's quoted in the example since it's an argument to the function, but it shouldn't be in quotes if you use the UI). Although I wouldn't be surprised if that is happening, ArcGIS does do some string conversion implicitly when going to/from Python.

Comment: @Hornbydd For the `CalculateField` arcpy tool, 'None' is the proper implementation for a null value. '"None"' would be the string of the word `None`. Think of what you would use in the field calculator, and then put that in (generally single-) quotes.